# Problem controlling an existing service from an activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, bind

I am an Android newbie. I am starting a service at Phone Boot Up. I would like to control this service from an activity I would launch later. I however am unable to do so.

Is it because I am launching the service from the BroadCastReceiver and there is some problem with the context? Can you let me know what I am doing wrong and how I should proceed. I would appreciate if anyone could explain how to proceed in this problem.

Here are my files:

**MyPhoneBoot.java**

```
package phone.Boot;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyPhoneBoot extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Log.d("MyPhoneBoot", "Phone Boot Captured");
    Intent expIntent=new Intent(context,MyService.class);
    context.startService(expIntent);
    }

}
```

**MyService.Java**

```
package phone.Boot;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

public static String TAG="MyNewService";
public static int service_running=999;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    service_running=2;
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    Log.d(TAG, "Value " + MyService.service_running);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    service_running=(-2);
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    Log.d(TAG, "Value " + MyService.service_running);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    service_running=1;
    Log.d(TAG, "Value " + MyService.service_running);
    Log.d(TAG, "Service has been started!");
}
public void onStop(Intent intent, int startid) {
    service_running=(-1);
    Log.d(TAG, "Value " + MyService.service_running);
    Log.d(TAG, "Service has been stopped!");
}

}
```

**MyActivity.Java**

```
package phone.Boot;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("MyActivity", "MyActivity running!" + MyService.service_running);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button myButton, myButton2;
    myButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    myButton2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    myButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

    /* changes done for binding service */
   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.button_1:
            switch (MyService.service_running)
            {
             case 2:
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Starting already created service!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Alrdy created -> Starting now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
                break;

             case 1:
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Trying to start existing service!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Alrdy Running!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

             case -2:
             case 999:
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Re-Starting Service");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Re-Starting Service!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
                break;
            }

            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            if(MyService.service_running == -1 || MyService.service_running == -2 || MyService.service_running == 999)
            {
                Log.d("MyActivity", "No Service To Stop!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to Stop! x-(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(MyService.service_running == 1 || MyService.service_running == 2)
            {
                Log.d("MyActivity", "Halting Service!!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping Service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                stopService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
            }
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="phone.Boot"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<receiver android:name="MyPhoneBoot">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
    </action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
<activity android:name="phone.Boot.MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi coder, I have added the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly you want is not clear. Do you want to stop the service or you want to start the service from the activity again and you are not getting the desired result. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157567/number-of-times-the-service-has-run/7157642#7157642) may help you.

Comment: Hi Vineet. I am starting a service when the Phone boots up. This is evident from the MyPhoneBoot.java class. I can see that the service has started from the logs placed in the MyService class. Now I would like to control this same service using the activity I have created. 
My question is that:
1. Why can't I see this service after going to Settings->Application->Running Services
2. How I can I control a service started in BroadCastReceiver from an activity I shall launch later on...

Hope that provides some clarification. 
Thanks for your help!!!! :)

Comment: What type of control you are talking about? what do you want to do from your activity?

Comment: I would like to be able to start and stop the service from my activity. What I want to do is this:

1. As soon as the phone boots up, I shall start a service.

2. Through logs put in the code, I can see that my service is running however I cannot see it in Settings->Application->Running Services

3. Letting this service run the entire time, I would also like to start/stop this service by a separate application(MyActivity).

4. The problem I am facing is that how do I link to this service I have already spawned at the phone boot up. Is this clear?

Comment: you can start or stop service only thru the app to which it is associated not from any other app......

Answer (score 0):

I am also a noobie, but I've created something similar to you and it works great.
First of all, since the service and activity are part of the same project, you can start and stop the service fine from the activity.  Launching on boot doesn't make a difference (I stop and start my boot services fine from my activity).

A couple of things: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?
Does the app crash?  What value do you get from service_running when you try to access it from the activity?

Also, I'm not too sure about the service lifecycle.  Though you don't explicitly stop it, it only runs code once.  The service has long since completed its code by the time you've finished your boot process and accessed your activity.  If you can't access the service_running variable, I'm guessing the service is dead and it has ceased to exist, though I could be wrong - I'm a noob after all :-)

Try creating a repetitive service (like a GPS listener which will run forever), and see if that keeps it alive.